# How to avoid foreign key constraint violationin in entity relationships using JPA

Tags: java, jdbc, eclipselink, jpa-2.1, java-ee-8

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTENCE_USER")

    public class User implements Serializable {
        // HERE IS A SNIPPET
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    
        private Long id;
        @NotNull
        private String firstName;
        @NotNull
        private String lastName;
        ................
    }
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTENCE_ORDER")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = "findAllorders",
            query = "SELECT o FROM CustomerOrder o"
    ),
    @NamedQuery(
            name = "deleteAll",
            query = "DELETE FROM CustomerOrder"
    )
})

    public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {
    
        //HERE IS A SNIPPET
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        @NotNull
        String status;
        @NotNull
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<LineItem> lineItems;
        @NotNull
        @ManyToOne
        private User customer;
        ...........
    }
```

When I try to delete the CustomerOrder entity that has a unidirectional @ManyToOne with the User entity, I get the following error:

```
Internal Exception: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.DerbySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'PERSISTENCE_ORDER' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'PRSSTNCSRPRSSRDRSD' for key (21).  The statement has been rolled back.
Error Code: 20000
Call: DELETE FROM PERSISTENCE_ORDER
Query: DeleteAllQuery(name="deleteAll" referenceClass=CustomerOrder sql="DELETE FROM PERSISTENCE_ORDER")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:967)
        ............................................................................
        ............................................................................
Caused by: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.DerbySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'PERSISTENCE_ORDER' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'PRSSTNCSRPRSSRDRSD' for key (21).  The statement has been rolled back.
```

Afterward, I tried to delete the User entity first before deleting the CustomerOrder entity but that didn't make any difference. How should I define the entity-relationship mappings to avoid this error?

Thanks

PS: I am using Glassfish 5.1 with EclipseLink running on Windows 10 64 bits and Apache Derby DB

Comment: You aren't deleting a single Entity instance here using JPA entityManager.remove logic, you seem to be issuing a "DELETE FROM CustomerOrder" bulk delete query. JPA doesn't do anything for you - it issues the SQL exactly as this JPQL would demand - so it is up to you to maintain by nulling out or removing any references to the rows you want to delete, before you delete them. We can't tell what else might be referencing your CustomerOrder, but you seem to have a list of LineItems that likely map to a table that would need its rows cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks Chris. You 're right. Since I composed this post last week, I have changed my entity mappings as shown in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66425106/why-eclipselink-2-1-jpa-drop-and-create-is-not-working but now I am grappling with a different problem. If you make your comment into the answer, I will check it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When issuing a "DELETE FROM CustomerOrder" bulk delete query, JPA doesn't do anything for you - it issues the SQL exactly as this JPQL would demand - so it is up to you to maintain by nulling out or removing any references to the rows you want to delete, before you delete them.

The exception itself states FK constraint 'PRSSTNCSRPRSSRDRSD' was violated, which could be found in the database to tell you exactly which relationship is causing the issue. Looking at the CustomerOrder entity, it the lineItems collection is being mapped in a way that puts the foreign key in the LineItems table, and this would require those rows to be cleaned up before the delete would be successful.